# Hot reloading with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to configure hot reloading for server-side-rendered Angular Universal but I could not find any clear steps that worked for me, since this is a fairly new thing and I'm not that experienced with Webpack and build configurations. The goal is that upon hitting save on a file the server code will be rebuilt and re-served. I'm not that fussed at all about automatic reload of the browser, but I would like to find the most optimal and fastest way of automatically rebuilding and re-serving the code. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

this is my server.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

This is the webpack.server.config:

```
// Work around for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  //watch: true,
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

And these are my scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
  "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
  "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
  "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod --aot && ng run connect-edge:server:production",
  "ssr": "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr",
},
```

Comment: Burner?
I've been trying to figure this out myself, just saw this which i might try: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/490#issuecomment-343919512